# How to declare specific module with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would to declare specific module because
I load on every page all my angular files..
It's huge.
I want to load specifically angular files on each page.

My app.js file that looks like this :

```
var testApp = angular.module(
'testApp', [
    'MainCtrl',
    'AdminCtrl',
    'UserCtrl',
    'ArticleCtrl',
    'ArticleService', 
    'MediaService',
    'UserService',
],
function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
}
);
```

But it wants to declare modules that are no longer loaded.
So instead of making a specific app.js for each page I need..

Anyone has a better idea ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of requirejs where modules will be loaded on demand.

A very nice tutorial how to achieve this:

[Lazy loading angular components](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2554-loading-angularjs-components-with-requirejs-after-application-bootstrap.htm)